# Unable to track reputation change

Tags: support, reputation

A day before I had a reputation of 1430 but next day my reputation changed to 1428, with no trace of any reputation change. Can some one guide me what could have possibly happened?

Comment: Possibly a suggested edit where the post was later deleted.

Comment: On [your reputation page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/253446/shashank-chaturvedi?tab=reputation), check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom left. Does this reveal anything useful?

Comment: Do you really think its a duplicate the link you mention starts with a question "When I visit the reputation tab of my profile, I see a lot of stuff. I can make out some of it, but not all". Pardon me if I am missing something but I don't seem to find a link.

Comment: Bullet point #4: "My reputation suddenly dropped, but I don't see anything. What happened?" See the link?

Comment: Thanks Nick and hims056 checking the show removed post check box helped me find the problem. A post that I edited was actually deleted. Even though the link hims056 provided has a solution in the answer, still this not a duplicate question as this is about a specific scenario and not about generally understanding the SO features.

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi - Do we really need to keep open questions of specific scenario when the solution is same?