# Unable to see changes on reputation tab from downvotes

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes

A little while ago, I lost a little bit of rep from downvotes. However, there was no `-2` shown on my reputation tab, but when I clicked on the tab, I could see the changes. In other words, I had to click on the reputation tab to see the changes. Why do I need to click on it in order to see the changes?

**Related:**
[Unable to track reputation change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224042/unable-to-track-reputation-change)